# Express.JS Get Status Code from POST Request

Tags: node.js, express, https, response

I am needing to find a way to get a response as a result of a https post request. So far from what I hae found that is only provided in the call back function, which does not include the result after data is written to the request and is ended as shown below:

**Note: the code below would be wrapped inside a "app.post" method.

```
const https = require("https");
var url = "https://someurl.com";
var options = {option1: "some option"}
var jsonData = {data1: "some data"};
const request = https.request(url, options, function (repsonse) {
// HERE THE STATUS CODE ONLY CAPTURES IF THE RESOURCE WAS AVAILABLE 
// NOT IF THE REQUEST WAS SUCCESSFUL
console.log(response.statusCode);
});
request.write(jsonData);
request.end();
```

After the "request.end()" code i need to be able to get the status code returned from the request to determine if the actual request was successful. I would want to do something like this:

```
if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
}
else {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
}
```

The if statement should run after request.end() to determine if the actual request was successful. This is standard for using API frameworks such as Flask-Python, but I can't seem to find a way to catch this in express.js. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using if statement in the https.request callback parameter
something like this: 
```const request = https.request(url, options, function (repsonse) {
if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
}
else {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
}
console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https.request` works *asynchronously*. Whether the request is successful or not cannot be determined synchronously after the `request.end()`, but only in the callback function (where you can evaluate `response.statusCode`) or in the `error` event (if the request could not be made at all, for example because the server was unreachable).

```js
const request = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  if (response.statusCode !== 200)
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  else
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
});
request.on("error", function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
});
request.write(jsonData);
request.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This works a lot different than what i'm used to with Flask-Python.  In my post request I am attempting to subscribe to a mailchimp but i noticed even when i try and subscribe a user that is already subscribed (as a means of testing) i am still getting statusCode '200'. Would it be possible that is the response statusCode that Mailchimp is sending, or would i check the request. on("error") for a possible different status code?

Comment: If Mailchimp finds out that the user is already subscribed, it will _not_ produce an "error" but complete the request with a response. I don't know what status that response has and what content, but it could even be a status 200.

Comment: got it, that makes sense knowing that. I was expecting to see a status code change. In this case it's likely the if statement checking the status code wouldn't be the best way to determine if the user was actually subscribed or not , rather look for other details in the response content that would determine a successful confirmation or not. Thanks for your help!